# SMTP Server not sending Email

Tags: c#, iis, smtp, iis-6, smtpclient

I am beginner and don't have any idea to send emails using our own smtp server. I am trying to send Email using my SMTP server. and here is my code

```
 public void SendEmail(string to, string subject, string body)
    {
        var fromaddr = FromAddress;
        var password = Password;

        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage
        {
            Subject = subject,
            From = new MailAddress(fromaddr),
            Body = body
        };
        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = SmtpHost,
            Port = 25,
            UseDefaultCredentials = true,
            EnableSsl = false
        };
        NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential(fromaddr, password);
        smtp.Credentials = nc;
        smtp.Send(msg);
    }
```

and in SmtpHost i store "localhost". and i have also installed smtp on my web server. and in iis if i choose "store in email directory". i got emails in given directory but if i choose deliver email to smtp server then i won't receive any email in my inbox.

on this option i am giving these values

smtp server : localhost

use localhost : checked

post : 25

authentication settings : not required

can you help me out?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, have you checked the junk box? Also, why do you set a password, when you say that no authentication is required?

Comment: i haven't do email using my own smtp so i don't have idea...i use this code for sending email using gmail smtp and it's work fine...

Comment: "I don't have an idea" about the authentication or about checking the junk box. Check the junk box, you might be actually receiving emails, but many engines will mark them as spam/junk if you haven't followed some practices in email delivery - e.g. spf records

Comment: no there is no email in junk @LIvanov

Comment: Could you elaborate on where is this "store in email directory" setting you are referring to

Comment: basically when we are setting mail setting in IIS there are 2 options...and when i select store in email directory and give path of directory it store outlook file as a mail in that folder when i send email.